# How to place JQuery error label dynamically after validating from server

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working on signup form. I've validated the fields for required, minlength etc, and placed validate error message before an element like this:

```
$('#register').validate(
{
    rules: 
    {
        username: 
        {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        email: 
        {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: 
        {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        confirmPassword: 
        {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    },
    messages: 
    {
        username:
        {
            required: 'Please enter username',
            minlength: 'Username too short'
        },
        email: 
        {
            required: 'Please enter email',
            email: 'Invalid E-Mail'
        },
        password:
        {
            required: 'Please enter password',
            minlength:'Password too short'
        },
        confirmPassword: 
        {
            required: 'Please provide password',
            equalTo: 'Passwords don\'t match'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element)
    {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

All is fine while client side validation, but I've to check for the server side validation too, like username duplication, email duplication... So if username already exists, and I've to place validate error message before an element again, then how it would be? I've done all ajax, request and php/mysql coding and returning error message. Just I've to display before an element with same style as jquery validating do.

Comment: How is `errorPlacement` called?

Comment: <label for="username" generated="true" class="error">Please enter username</label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom validation functions to each element. like for example say you need to add ajax validation to "username" field, this can be done as follows

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateUserName", function(val, element) {

    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        async: false,
        url : YOUR_URL,
        data : {'username': val},
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert("some error occured while submitting the form");
            return false;
        },
        success : function(  response,  textStatus,  jqXHR ){
            //Assuming you return true in server reply
            if( response.status == true ){
                //Username valid
                return true;
            } else {
                //Invalid Username
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}, "Username Already exists.");
```

And your validation js will look somehting like this

```
$('#register').validate(
{
    rules: 
    {
        username: 
        {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            validateUserName: true,
        },
 .....
```

So now when there is a repeat username, the custom error "Username Already exists." will be shown in its error label.

Comment: does this help? please give your feedbacck.

Comment: Still I've not tried, but I am sure that It'll work. I am trying it now.

Comment: It didn't work. Whatever boolean value (either true or false) is returned from server, It display message: 'Username already exists.' Besides why have you added statement: var usernameVal = $(element).val(); when value of text-field is already in val parameter.

Comment: Yes you can choose val or $(element).val() Also, since we are doing an ajax call in the function, the function "validateUserName" does not wait for the ajax response to complete. I am thinking of a workaround,  you can wait for an update from me on the above.

Comment: I have updated the above code to make the ajax call synchronously, this way the function will wait for the response of the ajax call and return the response accordingly. I have added " async: false," to the ajax call

Comment: No, It didn't. Still it contain mistake. But I corrected it myself. I am telling you, where you made serious mistake. Anyway, thanks a lot. Without your help, my problem wouldn't have been solved.

Comment: @MudasirBhutto, please do not edit code within another user's answer.  Simply comment, vote, or post your own more correct answer.

Comment: @MudasirBhutto I am also a learner as all of us here. Sorry for the mistake m glad that you solved it and got it working. glad i could help in any way

Answer (score 0):

Here, It worked. Please correct your code, so I should mark it as right answer.

```
var isSuccess ;
$.validator.addMethod('validateUserName', function(val, element)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
     type : 'post',
     async: false,
     url :  'include/validateUser.php',
     data : {'username': val},
     dataType : 'json',
     error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
        alert('some error occured while submitting the form');
     },
     success : function(response,  textStatus,  jqXHR )
     {
        isSuccess = response ;
     }
    });
   return isSuccess ;
}, 'Username Already exists.');
```